Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML: префикс не связан c пространством имён (у поставщика RSS)
У поставщика rss-каналов случилась: Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML (см.рис).
Через view-source: структура xml корректная, проверял даже валидатором.
Если открыть данный url и сохранить на свой ресурс и подключить, то всё работает отлично. Но rss в таком случает  быстро теряет актуальность (это новости).
Как можно обойти, выйти из этой ситуации?
Имеется ли "лекарство" в виде скрипта, конвертора или чего-то подобного для правильной работы rss-потоков от поставщика?
Пока в рамках своей компетенции вижу лишь выход в том, чтобы писать что-то в направлении загрузчика rss-файлов от поставщика, а далее загрузки их на свои ftp?


Ну в первую очередь ругайте своего «поставщика rss-каналов» чтобы он исправил свою ошибку

@andreymal, с поставщиком нельзя ругаться, я забираю rss по своему усмотрению, составляя на их основе конкурентный продукт - информационно-новостные порталы. Не думаю, что он меня за это поблагодарит и тут же начнёт править rss. Проект поставщика в виде сайта работает прекрасно.
Из опыта знаю, что такие заявки игнорируются в 90% СМИ. И исправляются тогда, когда угодно владельцам ресурсов.
Но согласен - как вариант тоже имеет место быть.
